# Compiling java code error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I want to compile file named SetPoint.java there're errors:

```
SetPoint.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Point point = new Point();
        ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class SetPoint
SetPoint.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Point point = new Point();
                          ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class SetPoint
2 errors
```

I have this two files (Point.java and SetPoint.java) in folder named xyz. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If I do the same in IntelliJ it works correctly.

```
package xyz;

public class Point {
    int coorX;
    int coorY;
}
```

.

```
package xyz;

public class SetPoint {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Point point = new Point();
        point.coorX = 10;
        point.coorY = 20;

        System.out.println("Coordinate of point: ("+point.coorX+", "+point.coorY+")");
    }

}
```

Comment: So the error is occurring when you compile from the command line? Can you share the command you're using?

Comment: I used only "javac SetPoint.java".

Comment: Yup, then Elliott's answer below is correct :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile both java files at the same time,

```
javac *.java
```

**or**

```
javac SetPoint.java Point.java
```